# How can I find the unconditional variance of this process?

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, moving-average

Let $y_t = \Delta p_t$ denote a time series of asset returns, where $p_t$ are logarithmic prices. $y_t$ is generated by a heteroskedastic MA(1) process
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= z_t+\theta z_{t-1}, \\ 
z_t &= \sqrt{h_t} \epsilon_t, \\ 
h_t &= \omega+\alpha z_{t}^2+\beta h_{t-1}, \\ 
\epsilon_t &\sim iid (0,1). \\
\end{aligned}
In addition, $\omega>0$, $\alpha>0$, $\beta<1$ and $\alpha+\beta<1$.

Derive expressions for

- The unconditional mean of the process, $E(y_t)$ ----> For this first point I got $E(y_t) = 0$ since it's the sum of the expected value of the sum of 2 zero-mean variables
- The unconditional variance $\text{Var}(y_t)$ ----> For this point I am stuck. What I did so far is
  $$
  \text{Var}(y_t) = E(z_t^2+\theta^2 z_{t-1} ^2  ) = E(h_t+\theta^2 h_{t-1}).
  $$
  How can I get the final expression for the unconditional variance?

What is weird for me is that $h_t = \omega+\alpha z_t^2+\beta h_{t-1}$  instead of $h_t = \omega+\alpha z_{t-1}^2+\beta h_{t-1}$.
If a consider a typo in $h_t$ then the unconditional variance is
$$
\gamma(0) = \frac{\omega(1+\theta^2)}{1-(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
Is my result correct?

Then I am asked to find the autocorrelation function of $y_t$, $\rho(k)$, for $k = 1,2$. I am having trouble to find the autocovariance at lag 1.
$$
\gamma(1) = E(z_t+\theta z_{t-1})(z_{t-1}+\theta z_{t-2}) = \theta E(z_{t-1}^2)
$$
I would say that $\gamma(1) = \frac{\theta \omega}{1-(\alpha+\beta)}$ but I am completely unsure of this result.

Regarding $\rho(2)$ should be equal to $0$ because $\gamma(2) = 0$.

Can someone tell me how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I initially closed this question because I misread it: it is very difficult to distinguish "$\varepsilon_t$" from "$\epsilon_t$" in some browsers.

Comment: I see , I am changing notation to make  the question clearer

Comment: I think it should be $z_{t-1}^2$ instead of $z_t^2$ in the conditional variance equation. Then your process is MA(1)-GARCH(1,1). Otherwise you get a circular definition where $z_t$ defines $h_t$ and the other way around.

Comment: yes, do you think that the equation for the variance I got is correct?